# iPhone: create new "View-based Application" = no view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have created a new iPhone "View-based Application" in Xcode. I then added a new "UIViewController subclass" and checked the "with XIB for user interface. Now the issue I have is that after hooking up all the variables and message handlers, I cannot push the new controller onto the stack using the following code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.cabinetController
                                     animated:YES];
```

All the variables and views are hooked up correctly, so all that I can think of is that its the way I am doing it, by pushing it onto the "navigationController". Is there something I am missing here? (I am very new to iPhone and Apple programming in general, so its probably a very simple oversight).

I realise that not enough information has been supplied ... here is a link to the project. Please note that it is an educational exercise has some creatively names classes.

http://files.me.com/nippysaurus/4yqz8t

Comment: You will have to provide some more code if you want us to understand your problem...

Comment: @Michael: Sorry, here is a link to the project. http://files.me.com/nippysaurus/4yqz8t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your appDelegate create a UINavigationController instance variable and then use your existing viewController as the rootViewController of the navigation controller.

e.g. in pure code using a UITableViewController (you can use xibs as well which your template app probably does).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

  // Create root view and navigation controller
  UITableViewController *rootViewController = [[[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
  self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController] autorelease];

  // Not necessary if you're using xibs
  self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

  // Add the nav controller's root view to the window
  [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your view controller to a navigation controller, with its root view controller set as the current view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine your `self.navigationController`, you will realize it is `nil`. Messaging nil doesn't hurt, so no error message here.

Add another layer with a `UINavigationController`, and add your `RandomShitViewController` (nice name btw.) as its root view controller.

The navigation controller handles the push / pop part, your old controller manages its view.